# Order history comment data is not post after adding tiny MCE

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, tinymce

I am using Magento Latest version 1.9.3.

I have added tiny MCE editor on order history comment like below

[image]

While i have submit comment. history comment data is not post in `addComment` function.

for display editor i have use below code

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "exact",
    elements: "history_comment",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "inlinepopups,style,spellchecker,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect, | ,forecolor,backcolor,spellchecker",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_path_location : "bottom",
    extended_valid_elements : "a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]",
    theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : 'true',
    theme_advanced_resizing : 'true',
    apply_source_formatting : 'true',
    convert_urls : 'false',
    force_br_newlines : 'true',
    setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
          //ed.getBody().setAttribute('spellcheck', true);
           setTimeout(function () {
              tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager.setActive('spellchecker', true);  tinymce.execCommand('mceSpellCheck', true);
             }, 1); 
       });
     },
     //tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager.setActive.setAttribute('spellchecker', true),
     //tinyMCE.execCommand('mceSpellCheck', true),
    doctype : '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'

  });
};
```

Please let me know if any one have idea about this.